# struct.unpack(struct.pack(float)) has roundoff error?

Tags: python, floating-point, pack

When testing my library, [Construct](https://github.com/construct/construct), I found out that tests fail when numbers are built then parsed back to a float. Should floats not be represented exactly as in-memory floats?

```
In [14]: d = struct.Struct("<f")

In [15]: d.unpack(d.pack(1.23))
Out[15]: (1.2300000190734863,)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Floating point is inherently imprecise, but you are packing a double-precision float (`binary64`) into a single-precision (`binary32`) space there. See [*Basic and interchange formats*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Basic_and_interchange_formats) in the Wikipedia article on IEEE floating point formats; the Python `float` format uses double precision (see the [standard types docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex); *Floating point numbers are usually implemented using double in C*).

Use `d` to use double precision:

```
>>> import struct
>>> d = struct.Struct("<d")
>>> d.unpack(d.pack(1.23))
(1.23,)
```

From the [*Format characters* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters):

> format: `f`, C Type: `float`, Python type: `float`, Standard size: `4`, Footnote: (5)
>   format: `d`, C Type: `double`, Python type: `float`, Standard size: `8`, Footnote: (5)
>
> 5. For the `'f'` and `'d'` conversion codes, the packed representation uses the IEEE 754 binary32 (for `'f'`) or binary64 (for `'d'`) format, regardless of the floating-point format used by the platform.